# SQL Function with dynamic date parameter

Tags: sql-server

I have a function that I want to use a date dynamic parameter, but I am getting an error "The multi-part identified "func_RunCode" cound not be bound".

```
SELECT func_RunCode '1/1/2016', '''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE()-1,101) + '''','N'
```

I want to replace the second date parameter with a dynamic date instead of hard coding the second date. Any suggestions?

Comment: try to call it with Schema name. e.g. dbo.func_RunCode(...), and also make sure the name is correct

Comment: You seem to be missing parentheses

Comment: the schema is Process. Figured it out. im missing the "SELECT * FROM"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT dbo.func_RunCode ('1/1/2016', '''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE()-1,101) + '''','N')
```